# PutText in haskell HUnit

Tags: haskell, hunit

I have recently been using the HUnit testing framework to run unit
tests in haskell.

I came across this function PutText and runTestText which takes
PutText st as its first argument.

However i am not sure how to use this and would like some help in understanding how to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PutText value allows you to customize the way to messages generated from running a test are reported.

A simple way to create one is use `putTextToHandle stdout True` to output messages to standard out. The `True` parameter means to also emit progress messages.

The PutText protocol allows you to maintain state. This is an example of one that keeps track of the number of messages emitted. The final value
of this state is also returned by `runTestText` as the second component
of the returned tuple.

```
reportMsg :: String -> Bool -> Int -> IO Int
reportMsg message isProgress count = do
  putStrLn $ "#" ++ show (count+1) ++ ": " ++ message
  return (count+1)

myPutText = PutText reportMsg 0  :: PutText Int
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
(testCounts, msgCount) <- runTestText myPutText tests
putStrLn $ "Messages emitted: " ++ show msgCount
```

Here `testCounts` is a tally of the number of tests which were run / passed / failed / etc. The `msgCount` is the value returned by the last call to the PutText function.

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering what purpose does the bool argument serve?

Comment: It indicates whether or not the message is a "progress" message - I presume like reporting the number of tests currently completed.

Comment: Whenever i try to use it, it always turns out to be false. Im not sure why, any ideas?